# libGDX getColor() method

Tags: button, libgdx

I have a grid of buttons, displayed on a stage. Setting and getting the color of the buttons is behaving strangely.

```
int X=0;
int Y=0;
buttons[X][Y].setColor(Color.BLUE);  //this works, the button displays blue
boolean test = (buttons[X][Y].getColor()==Color.BLUE);
System.out.println(test);  //prints 'false' , why???
System.out.println(buttons[X][Y].getColor()); //prints '0000ffff'
System.out.println(Color.BLUE); //prints '0000ffff'
```

I need to be able to set and get the color of the buttons for the game I'm creating. Does anyone know what is going on and what I could do?

Comment: You're comparing references instead of values. You could use `boolean test = buttons[X][Y].getColor.equals(Color.BLUE);` instead.

Comment: Thank you Xoppa! I really appreciate your helpful and positive answer.

Comment: `buttons[X][Y].getColor().equals(Color.BLUE) `  - this is what actually works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Color objects are different, but they have the same value.  So, the objects may not be `==` equal but will be `.equal()` equal.  See [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)